# How to cool a liquid the most efficient way by submerging solids into it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

Consider a certain amount of liquid, and also a solid body of certain mass. The solid is at a lower temperature than the liquid. The goal is to cool the liquid by submerging the solid, and they can't dissolve. The liquid doesn't solidificate either.

The solid can be divided into pieces, and these can be submerged one by one, so that after the piece-liquid system enters thermic equilibrium, the piece is retrieved so that the next one can be added, an so on.

My question is, in which way should I divide the solid (and if the pieces have different mass, in which order should they be added) so that the minimal temperature is achieved?

I tried writing down some equations, first to solve for the final temperature, and then to compare absorbed heats, for just one division, but they got very messy very quickly. I'm a bit stuck, so any input to solve the problem is deeply appreciated.

Consider that I'm lookin for minimal final temperature, not quickest time.

Comment: Are you allowing the liquid to equilibrate thermally with each piece of solid before the next piece of solid is added?

Comment: At first I was confused at how splitting the solid helps at all, since I equated it to the intuitive experience of dropping ice into a drink, in which case the drink's final temperature doesn't depend how you break the ice up. But that's not a very good analogy, I think the key here is that you take ice back out of the glass to avoid needing to keep the mass of the ice itself cool in addition to the liquid (some of the ice ends up warmer than the final minimal temperature).

Comment: Is that a yes or a no?

Comment: @ChetMiller Doesn't "so that after the piece-liquid system enters thermic equilibrium, the piece is retrieved so that the next one can be added" answer your question?

Comment: @JimmyJames Right, crushed ice will cool a drink *faster* than cubed since heat transfer is higher with more surface area, but it doesn't cool it any *more* since the total energy content is identical in both cases. The key difference here is not exactly that solid gets added bit-by-bit, it's that some solid gets taken back out before the next bit is added.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I failed to read the last line of the question until after I commented.  Hence the deletion.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie That last bit about removing the pieces is a nice addition to the accepted answer.  My initial inclination was to think removing the pieces was irrelevant and now you've made me realize it's the most crucial aspect of the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider first the case where the solid is divided into two pieces. I will assume for simplicity that the heat capacities are independent of temperature. We have
$$C_1(T_1-T_s)=C_\ell(T_i-T_1)$$
$$C_2(T_2-T_s)=C_\ell(T_1-T_2)$$
where $C_\ell$ is the liquid heat capacity, $C_k$ is the heat capacity of piece $k$, $T_i$ is the initial liquid temperature, $T_s$ is the initial solid temperature and $T_k$ is the temperature after piece $k$ comes to equilibrium. The final liquid temperature (relative to the initial solid temperature) is given by
$$T_2 - T_s=\frac{C_\ell^2}{(C_\ell+C_1)(C_\ell+C_2)}(T_i-T_s)$$
$$=\frac{C_\ell^2}{C_\ell^2+C_\ell(C_1+C_2)+C_1C_2}(T_i-T_s).$$
First, note that this expression remains unchanged if you swap $C_1$ and $C_2$, meaning *the order in which the pieces are submerged has no impact*. Second, for the lowest temperature, the denominator must be maximized, subject to $C_1+C_2=C_s$: the total solid heat capacity. This requires that $C_1C_2$ be maximized, which happens when $C_1=C_2=C_s/2$, i.e. *when the pieces have equal size* (mass).

Now we can generalize to the case of an arbitrary number of pieces, say $N$. Since we know that the order in which any two consecutive pieces is submerged has no effect, we can start with a particular ordering, then reorder two consecutive pieces at a time to obtain *any* ordering, without affecting the final temperature. This shows that the final temperature still doesn't depend on the ordering in the general case.  Since swapping any two pieces $n$ and $k$ has no effect, we must have $C_n = C_k$ for the optimal ordering, therefore all pieces must have the same heat capacity $C_s/N$ and hence the same size to achieve the lowest final liquid temperature.

So the answer to your question is:

- The more pieces you divide the solid into, the lower the final liquid temperature. The order in which they are submerged doesn't matter.
- The pieces must be equally sized for the lowest final liquid temperature.

You might then ask how much you can possibly cool the liquid, in the limit of infinitely many pieces. The energy balance after after a tiny piece with heat capacity $dC$ is submerged gives
$$C_\ell dT = -dC(T-T_s)$$
$$\int\limits_{T_i}^{T_f}\frac{dT}{T-T_s}=-\int\limits_{0}^{C_s}\frac{dC}{C_\ell}$$
$$\log\left(\frac{T_i - T_s}{T_f - T_s}\right)=\frac{C_s}{C_\ell}$$
$$T_f - T_s=e^{-C_s/C_\ell}(T_i - T_s)$$
where $T_f$ is the final temperature of the liquid.

Comment: how does breaking the solid into more pieces result in a lower final temperature? That seems to violate conservation of energy?

Comment: Consider that the pieces are added one by one and retrieved when they achieve equilibrium. So in the end,  in each heat transfer, each solid chunk is at the initial temperature Ts, while the liquid's temperature is reduced in each process. Conservation of energy is not violated.

Comment: So does this mean the the best result would be achieved if one could infinitely divide the solid so that it effectively becomes a liquid?

Comment: @ACarter At the end, the average temperature of the solid pieces will be higher if the pieces are smaller, so energy conservation isn't violated. Consider also the fact that the only equations I used here are statements of conservation of energy.

Comment: @MPW I think a "powder" is a more apt description, but yes, that's the idea. But crucially, you are limited not only by how finely you can crush the solid into pieces, but also how feasibly you can submerge them and fish them out of the liquid bit by bit: you aren't dumping it into the liquid all at once. There also wouldn't be a substantial difference in terms of final temperature between pieces the size of a sand grain and and even finer, powder-like pieces.

Comment: @ACarter Rates are irrelevant for this problem, just assume a well-insulated apparatus. The OP could not be more explicit that they are defining efficiency in terms of final temperature and not cooling time.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban Please read the question carefully. "Most efficient" here just means "the lowest final temperature of the liquid", and explicitly has nothing to do with how long it takes for it to be achieved. Since thermal equilibrium is achieved in each step, heat transfer rates are irrelevant in this problem.

Comment: @Puk my apologies. I did miss the last sentence of the post so i deleted my comments . The lowest final temperature can never be less than the temperature of the solid. So it seems that dividing into pieces gives greater temperature control and precision of the temperature  of the liquid but I don't see how it's more efficient.What is being optimized by dividing into smaller pieces?

Comment: Also, it takes energy to divide the solid into tiny pieces which lowers the overall efficiency of the process. Not to mention the energy required to insert and remove individual pieces and the measurements required to ensure the system is in equilibrium between piece insertion. Seems very inefficient if you include these factors.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban What is optimized is the final temperature of the liquid. If you drop in the whole solid and remove it after it comes to equilibrium, the liquid is cooler than before. If instead you divide the solid into two, then submerge and remove each piece one after another, the liquid is even cooler than in the first case. Again, since "efficiency" just refers to the final temperature of the liquid, any energy you expend to divide the solid into pieces doesn't factor in.

Comment: Ok. So if I take a 1 gram cube at temperature T and place it in a liquid at a higher temperature and then take two 0.5 gram half cubes into another liquid at the same temperature. Are you claiming after all equilibrium conditions are met that the final temperature of the liquids will be different in these two cases?

Comment: @StevanV.Saban If you add and remove the two cubes one by one, and not both at once, yes. You also need to wait until each cube reaches equilibrium.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. This problem seems to challenge my intuition

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, in which way should I divide the solid (and if the pieces have different mass, in which order should they be added) so that the minimal temperature is achieved?

Since you are removing pieces once equilibrium is reached the thermal mass of the liquid doesn't change.

For two bodies at different temperatures brought into contact, the heat transfered to reach equilibrium is conserved:

$$Q_L + Q_S = 0$$ or $$Q_L = -Q_S$$

For a single solid mass: $$m_Lc_L\Delta T_L = -m_Sc_S\Delta T_S $$

Now if the mass is divided into N pieces of equal mass $m_p$, then $$m_S=m_pN$$

Substituting and rearranging gives:
$$\frac{m_Lc_L\Delta T_L}N = -m_pc_S\Delta T_S$$ or $$\frac{Q_L}N = -q_p$$

Summing the individual pieces over N yields the single piece result.

The is no difference in the final temperature of the liquid because nothing has changed the quantity of heat that was transferred.

If the pieces are added and left in the container then each cube will change the thermal mass of the liquid: $$M = m_Lc_L + im_pc_S$$ where i is the piece number. This clearly gives a result that is different from the single cube case and will yield a higher final temperature since each $q_p$ cools a successively heavier liquid+solid combination.

One cube is best for minimum temperature (and effort) but it requires the most time to reach equilibrium.

Comment: In the OP scenario, the pieces are added one at a time, with each piece removed before the next one is added. So the final temperature (at removal time) of each piece is higher than the final temperature of all the subsequent pieces.

Comment: Yes but you are assuming that successive temperature changes will yield a different result than one large temperature change. Heat dictates temperature change and there is no difference in the quantity of heat thats transfered. I will edit my answer to address this.