# Thermodynamics brain teaser from TikTok

Tags: thermodynamics

The text below describes the TikTok video [here](https://www.tiktok.com/@marcbreathes/video/7217579866059885870).

Suppose you have 1L of blue water at 10C and 1L of red water at 55C. Assume you can pour water into a special jug with two compartments with 1L capacity each. Water in the two compartments of the jug can reach thermal equilibrium through the walls of the jug. You can also take water out of each compartment of the jug independently. No temperature changes occur except when the water mixes in the same container or when they are in the two-compartment jug. Can you make the blue water hotter than the red water?

The answer is yes. Take 0.5L of blue water at 10C and 1L of red water at 55C and pour it into the two compartments. The equilibrium temperature for these is 40C. Now remove the 40C blue water and pour the remaining 0.5L of blue water at 10C. This will reach equilibrium with the 1L of red water at 40C. The new equilibrium temperature is 30C. Combining all the blue water and they will reach 35C while the red water is at 30C.

**Question:**

How far can we take this process? Can I take infinitesimally small amounts of the blue water instead of taking half of it? If yes, how much hotter can I make the blue water compared to the red water and how? Would the answer change if I had access to more mixing containers?

Comment: I think you can have fun setting up an integral problem for this. And you can do even better than that algorithm if the mixing container is made such that cold blue water can be introduced from the bottom and extracted out the top, so that red water can be made to be cooler at the bottom and hotter at the top, which is a stable configuration, and water is a very poor conductor of heat, making this scheme rather efficient. i.e. more mixing containers, you can mimick this, so yes, it helps.

Comment: Actually, with the right setup, you can get the blue and red water to switch temperatures. Such a system is called a countercurrent heat exchanger, and they are ubiquitous in nature and engineering.

Comment: @knzhou just googled it and that's really smart!

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally as long as all of the red water remains in the jug, this problem identical to the one [in this recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/761018/how-to-cool-a-liquid-the-most-efficient-way-by-submerging-solids-into-it/) if you pose the question as "how much can we cool the red water", which is really the same as asking "how much can we warm the blue water" since energy is conserved.

We put all of the red water in one container of the jug. We add the blue water in infinitesimal amounts into the other container, and move it to a separate container after it comes to equilibrium. As shown in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/761024/171547), the solution for the final temperature of the red water is
$$T_r^f - T_b^i = e^{-C_b/C_r}(T_r^i-T_b^i).$$
Here $r$ denotes red, $b$ denotes blue, $i$ denotes initial, $f$ denotes final and $C$ denotes heat capacity. To state this in terms of the final temperature of the blue water, assuming the heat capacities don't vary with temperature, from energy conservation we have
$$C_bT_b^i + C_rT_r^i = C_bT_b^f + C_rT_r^f$$
$$T_r^f = T_r^i +\frac{C_b}{C_r}(T_b^i-T_b^f)$$
$$ T_r^i +\frac{C_b}{C_r}(T_b^i-T_b^f)-T_b^i=e^{-C_b/C_r}(T_r^i-T_b^i)$$
$$T_b^f=T_b^i+\frac{C_r}{C_b}\left(1-e^{-C_b/C_r}\right)(T_r^i-T_b^i).$$

Since we have the same quantities of red and blue water, $C_r = C_b$, so
$$T_b^f=T_b^i+\left(1-e^{-1}\right)(T_r^i-T_b^i).$$
For $T_r^i=55\ ^\circ\text C$ and $T_b^i=10\ ^\circ\text C$, we get $T_b^f = 38.5\ ^\circ\text C$.
This is the highest temperature you can reach by adding and removing discrete amounts of blue water while all of the red water remains in the jug.